# Auto Generating partial classes

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

This is my first time using EF in VS2012 as I have been using 2010 for up until now. I have added the entity framework model and it adds 2 files with the extension .tt which I am sure was not present in VS2010. Under one of these it generates partial classes to match the entities. However I already have these partial classes in another manually created folder called Entites under the root of my app. This causes an issue on build as they conflict...

How do I either either stop them autogenerating or how do I make them play nice with my manually created partial classes? It is incredibly annoying that VS2012 does this without asking as it breaks my code!

Example of Auto Generated class

```
namespace StatisticsServer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Statistic
    {
        public int StatID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int FranchiseID { get; set; }
        public double StatValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example of Manually created class

```
namespace StatisticsServer.Entities
{
    public partial class Statistic
    {
        public static List<Statistic> GetStatisticsSet(int categoryID)
        {
            List<Statistic> statSet = new List<Statistic>();
            using (var context = new StatisticsTestEntities())
            {
                statSet = (from s in context.Statistics where s.CategoryID == categoryID select s).ToList();
            }
            return statSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the auto-generated classes and one of your manually created classes? Partial classes should work together, but you might have created duplicate properties/methods.

Comment: Updated question with examples

Comment: the error I get is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StatisticsServer.Statistic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StatisticsServer.Entities.Statistic>" I can obviously fix this by explicitly specifying the namespace before the type, but I would rather not have those stupid autogenerated classes there in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your manually created classes are in the same namespace as the auto-generated ones.

Otherwise the two classes will be seen as separate partial classes, and if you use both namespaces in the same calling class it cannot determine which class you mean.

So for example in your case you might have:

```
using StatisticsServer;
using StatisticsServer.Entities;
```

When you then declare an object of the type `Statistic` in that class the build will fail because the `Statistic` class exists in both namespaces.

Comment: In VS2010 I handle that by setting the "Custom Tool Namespace" property to the namespace of my manually created partial classes. Everything then works fine. I have done this in my 2012 project and if I delete the code out of the autogenerated files everything works fine. But then obviously they are recreated as soon as I update the model and it breaks again. I don't even want those autogenerated classes. They were not present in 2010 so what on earth are they being created for? Also why are they being created in a different namespace to the one I specified in the CustomTool Namespace property?

Comment: Are you using a different version of the Entity Framework? (i.e. EF4 in VS2010, EF5 in VS2012)

Comment: I assume I am using EF5 as it is a project created from scratch in VS2012. In 2010 it is EF4

Comment: Where did you change the Custom Tool Namespace setting? On the .tt file or on the .edmx file? I would suggest setting it on the .edmx file as that should change the namespace for all files underneath it.

Comment: I right clicked the edmx file and selected properties. The setting is in that properties window. My manual created partial classes work fine with EF as long as I delete the code from the autogenerated ones. So the namespace is being seen fine by EF but the autogenerated ones are then created in a different namespace for some reason.

Comment: And what happens if you explicitly set the Custom Tool Namespace of the .tt as well, and then regenerate the model?